# Unable to update a particular class in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to dynamically update a Date Time value in my page built using React.js. So, for reference, I started with the below article:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html#react-only-updates-whats-necessary.

But the date-time value is not updating.
Here is my code:

```
var WelcomeMsg = React.createClass({ 
  render : function()
  {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Hello , User...</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var ShowTime = React.createClass({ 
  render : function()
  {
    return (
    <div>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
      )

  }
});


var Form=React.createClass({
 render:function(){ return(
  <div>
    <WelcomeMsg/>
     <ShowTime/>
  </div>
  )}
});

ReactDOM.render(<Form/>,document.body);
setInterval(ShowTime, 1000);
```

I need ShowTime as a separate class.

Comment: You would need to set the time in the state and then update that state after every 1000ms and then when you update the state the component will itself rerender. The way you are calling setInterval won't help you in updating time.

Comment: Could you share expected and actual output?

Comment: @AanchalSharma : Expected output : [CodePen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gwoJZk?editors=0010)  Actual Ouput : Time is not updating dynamically.

Comment: @ShubhamJain : Could you please explain little with few codes or ref ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code is implemented in ES6.

```
class HelloWidget extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
            time: new Date().toLocaleString()
      };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        setInterval(() => {
          this.setState({ time : new Date().toLocaleString() })
        },1000)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.state.time}</div>
        )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Shubham Jain, remove setInterval from here:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Form/>,document.body);
setInterval(ShowTime, 1000);
```

In the ShowTime component, declare a state variable time.

```
this.state = {
  time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
},
```

and update that state using setInterval as:

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.setState({ time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString() })
}, 1000)
```

Then you can use `{this.state.time}` in place of `{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}` in render.